# iOS: Return a value from a function after network operation

Tags: ios, swift, closures

I have to return an array after network operation in a MLPAutoCompleteTextField delegate method. Any suggestions related to this is highly helpful.

```
func autoCompleteTextField(textField: MLPAutoCompleteTextField!, possibleCompletionsForString string: String!, completionHandler handler: (([AnyObject]!) -> Void)!) {
    //Perform network operation. Success and Failure conditions are handled below by implementing the protocol
    service.getData(string)

    //Have to return this only after network operation is completed either success or failure
    handler(autoCompleteSuggestionsArray)
}

//Handle successful network call 
func handleSuccess(model: Model) {
    autoCompleteSuggestionsArray.removeAll()
    for item in model.items {
        if let itemName = item.name {
            autoCompleteSuggestionsArray.append(itemName)
        }
    }
}

//Handle failed network call
//
func handleErrorWithMessage(message: String) {
    autoCompleteSuggestionsArray.removeAll()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having delegate methods for success and failure instead of callback closures is not a great approach for the reason shown in your example:  you can't include the arguments from the scope of your `autoCompleteTextField` method in the delegate methods. If you are able to change your service implementation to take closures instead of using a delegate, e.g. `service.getData(string:String, success:SuccessClosure, failure:FailureClosure)`, that would be a better situation overall.

If you aren't able to make that change, then you have to do something unfortunate, like this:

```
var autocompleteHandler:([AnyObject]->())? //Create a new property on your class to hold an optional reference to the handler that is visible to multiple methods

func autoCompleteTextField(textField: MLPAutoCompleteTextField!, possibleCompletionsForString string: String!, completionHandler handler: (([AnyObject]!) -> Void)!) {
    //Save reference to handler in scope that is also visible to delegate methods
    autocompleteHandler = handler

    //Perform network operation. Success and Failure conditions are handled below by implementing the protocol
    service.getData(string)
}

//Handle successful network call 
func handleSuccess(model: Model) {
    autoCompleteSuggestionsArray.removeAll()
    for item in model.items {
        if let itemName = item.name {
        autoCompleteSuggestionsArray.append(itemName)
        }
    }
    // Now that we have a result from the service, pass it to the saved handler if it is not nil
    autocompleteHandler?(autocompleteSuggestionsArray)
}

//Handle failed network call
func handleErrorWithMessage(message: String) {
    autoCompleteSuggestionsArray.removeAll()
    // Now that we have a result from the service, pass it to the saved handler if it not nil
    autocompleteHandler?(autocompleteSuggestionsArray)
}
```

Comment: You made my day.. Thanks! I can't use service.getData(string:String, success:SuccessClosure, failure:FailureClosure) because that is a global service used by many controllers and need to follow the same. Your suggestion in saving the handler to a variable and passing it on works.